# If one row meets condition, then all rows changed in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Quick question, how can I change all rows for one column, if one row in another column fits a certain condition in dplyr?

So, different examples:

```
df <- data.frame(one = c(1,0,1,NA,1))
df2 <- data.frame(one = c(0,0,0,NA,0))
df3 <- data.frame(one = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

Where a new column "two" would be all 1's if there are any 1's in the data. If there are no 1's in the "one" column, but there is a 0, then "two" would be all 0's. If there are no 1's or 0's, then "two" would be all NA.

So the result in this case would be:

```
df
one two
1   1
0   1
1   1
NA  1
1   1

df
one two
0   0
0   0
0   0
NA  0
0   0

df
one two
NA   NA
NA   NA
NA   NA
NA   NA
NA   NA
```

Doesn't need to be a loop as there won't be many cases of this, just a one-liner would be great. I feel like I'm missing the if(match()) equivalent in dplyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, for such conditions you can use [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html). It applies condition in order and conditions can be based on other columns. See examples.

```r
df <- data.frame(one = c(1,0,1,NA,1))
df2 <- data.frame(one = c(0,0,0,NA,0))
df3 <- data.frame(one = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df %>%
  mutate(two = case_when(
    # if any 1 in one then two == 1
    any(one == 1) ~ 1L,
    # if no 1 in one, but some 0, then two = 0
    any(one == 0) ~ 0L,
    # in any other cases, two = NA
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_
  ))
#>   one two
#> 1   1   1
#> 2   0   1
#> 3   1   1
#> 4  NA   1
#> 5   1   1
df2 %>%
  mutate(two = case_when(
    any(one == 1) ~ 1L,
    any(one == 0) ~ 0L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_
  ))
#>   one two
#> 1   0   0
#> 2   0   0
#> 3   0   0
#> 4  NA   0
#> 5   0   0
df3 %>%
  mutate(two = case_when(
    any(one == 1) ~ 1L,
    any(one == 0) ~ 0L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_
  ))
#>   one two
#> 1  NA  NA
#> 2  NA  NA
#> 3  NA  NA
#> 4  NA  NA
#> 5  NA  NA
```

Created on 2018-07-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! What does the L stand for in 1L/0L? Additionally, is NA_integer making NA an a different type?

Comment: `L` after a numeric means to have it as integer. In `case_when` you need to have the same type for all RHS terms in formulas. `NA` alone is logical. Here I used `1L` and `0L` so I need `NA_interger`. You can use `1` and `0` with `NA_real`.